# Can't switch between OS

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I want to remove Ubuntu from this PC.  When I restart the computer and try to arrow down to Windows 8, I am unable to use the keyboard. It just doesn't work. I need to be able to select Windows 8 to remove my partition and delete Ubuntu.

Comment: are you using a USB keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The description of you problem is imho a little bit confusing... 

For your information I use Ubuntu every day and I do not have any problems with my wifi... Windows 8 and Java ??? 

If I understand well enough your problem you want to remove the dual boot...

To do that:

- boot from the windows cd
- then you will have the possibility to open a dos prompt
- start with this command:

  > bootrec.exe /FixMbr
- reboot and check if you can boot windows...
- ***if not:***

  > bootrec.exe /FixBoot
- reboot and check if you can boot windows...
- ***if not:***

  > bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
- reboot and check if you can boot windows...

That should do the trick... If it is successful then you can get rid of the ubuntu partition (from the windows disk manager).

Comment: I am sorry it is confusing. I am very new to all of this.  I can't access Windows 8 at all.  My keyboard is not working when I start up the computer. I am unable to select anything. I have the repair disk for Windows, but can't use it because I can't change the settings in the BIOS, to allow me to boot from the disc drive, because of this problem.  I am basically stuck booting in to Ubuntu.

Comment: well... :-) imho your question has nothing to do in particular with ubuntu... Shutdown your PC. Use another keyboard. Restart. You keyboard has to be seen by the bios... Press F12 to enter the bios. Change the boot order to cd/dvd(1) then the hard disk(2). Reboot from the cd...